# What type of attacks will a SMTP server face if it does not have ratelimiting while sending mails?

Tags: denial-of-service, smtp

Assume a web site with some kind of mailer option, that doesn't implement any rate limiting: This enables users to send an unlimited amount of email per second.

Will SMTP face possible DoS attacks for that? Or any kind of problems? Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter if you use rate limiting or not. If you're running a public server, which accepts incoming connections, it is always and anywhere vulnerable for a DDoS. Rate limiting can be useful to not congest the system, it could be a possible countermeasure against DoS but does not, by far, protect fully against a DoS attack.

Comment: Yeah !! It's okay.I got you..Though I have a question. I am a beginner in this field. Let me know how do i know whether it accepts incoming connections or not? And also how to protect mailer against DoS attacks?

Comment: One easy way is to ping the server in question. Protecting against a DoS is difficult. It is almost impossible protecting against a Distributed Denial of Service (DDoS): You need a lot of bandwidth to support the sudden increase in traffic. A DoS on your SMTP server can be secured if you use authentication on your SMTP server. If someone is spamming the mail server you can at least block the account and stop the spamming/throttling.

Answer (score 2):

One of the difficulties in securing SMTP lies in the protocol itself, specifically the admonitions in RFC 5321 which give proscriptions on timing out a session.  A faithful implementation provides no facility for timing a session out.  Ideally one would want to ignore those recommendations, and set a session timeout for the mail session.  This will prevent for example any attacks where long delays are used to send data character by character with large mail sizes.  For example if you have a mail server with a 10MB mail size limit, it is fairly easy to write a script which delivers a fake mail to your server and writes a Lorem Ipsum message, one character at a time up to the 10MB limit, but delaying each character by 1 - 2 minutes.  Theoretically without a session limit such a mail session could run around 10 million minutes.  So now run a script that simply starts bots that do this from hundreds of places on the web, and pretty soon the bots will have all your connections tied up (assuming you have connection limits, or are using a connection pool).

Ideally, one would set up a timer from the time the DATA command was issued to the time that the "CRLF . CRLF" was issued.  Something like 5 minutes or so for the whole data to transmit should be reasonable.  And violate the RFC and simply drop the connection if it exceeds that timeout.  Well behaved clients will never come close to that limit and even people using the command line terminal ought to be able to send data within that time frame presuming they know how to type.